# How do I collapse multiple kill lines as one undo history in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was just wondering if there's elisp package/snippet out there that would merge multiple invocations of the same editing command into 1 undo history. For example, if I hold down C-k to kill 10 lines, is there a way to tell Emacs to collapse them all as 1 undo history where if I undo, instead of having to undo 10 times, I can just undo once?

(No answer that tells me to use C-u 10 C-k or something like that will be accepted)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to [advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) [`kill-append`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/kill_002dappend-function.html) which is called when you do <kbd>C-k</kbd> repeatedly:

```
(defadvice kill-append (after merge-undo activate)
  (let ((prev buffer-undo-list)
        (next (cdr buffer-undo-list)))
    ;; find the next undo boundary
    (while (car next)
      (pop next)
      (pop prev))
    ;; remove this undo boundary
    (setcdr prev (cdr next))))
```

To disable this, do <kbd>M-x ad-unadvise RET kill-append RET</kbd>.